# how to view very tall height uiview in interface builder?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, storyboard, interface-builder

I have very tall uiview (around 2000 px) in storyboards in interface builder.  I want to place textviews from top to bottom in this tall view.

The problem is I can only see at largest, what shows on the 4 inch screen.  How can I see the entire view to place textviews in interface builder?

Answer (score 4):

Can you make the outter view in IB larger?  It is probably set to the IPhone dimensions currently (568 height), but you can set it to freeform (click on the ViewController first in storyboard), and make it 2000px height.

[image: freeform]
[image: 2000]

Comment: i changed the height for the viewcontroller, however the view in IB stays about the size of an iPhone 4 screen.  This is even with the freeform option checked.  Is there something I should manipulate on the view too?

Comment: if i click on the view i can set the height, but if i click on the view controller the size inspector says no applicable.

Comment: my problem was top bar and bottom bar were not set to none